# messages does not delivered to RabbitMQ while using mass transit and outbox pattern

Tags: asp.net, rabbitmq, masstransit, outbox-pattern

im using `Outbox Pattern with MassTransit`, when i publish message, it will remain in the OutboxMessages table in the data base and it wont deliverd to broker and here is the configuration:

packages:

```
        <PackageReference Include="MassTransit" Version="8.0.15" />
        <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.14" />
        <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.RabbitMQ" Version="8.0.14" />
```

`Program.cs`

```
  private static void AddMessagingConfiguration(IServiceCollection services, WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
        {
            busConfigurator.AddConsumer<GtsDocumentConsumer>();
            busConfigurator.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<CompanyGoodsDbContext>(outboxConfigurator =>
            {
                outboxConfigurator.UseSqlServer();
                outboxConfigurator.UseBusOutbox();
                outboxConfigurator.QueryMessageLimit = 10;
                outboxConfigurator.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                outboxConfigurator.QueryTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            });

            busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((busContext, transportConfigurator) =>
            {               transportConfigurator.Host(builder.Configuration["EventBusSettings:HostAddress"], hostConfiguration =>
                {
                    hostConfiguration.Username(builder.Configuration["EventBusSettings:Username"]);
                    hostConfiguration.Password(builder.Configuration["EventBusSettings:Password"]);
                    
                });

                transportConfigurator.AutoStart = true;
                transportConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(5));
                transportConfigurator.UseScheduledRedelivery(r =>
                    r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
                transportConfigurator.ConfigureEndpoints(busContext);
            });
        });
    }
```

`appSetting.json:`

```
"EventBusSettings": {
        "HostAddress": "sgms-broker",
        "Username": "guest",
        "Password": "guest"
    }
```

Note that I `dockerize` the app and its work perfectly fine, the term `sgms-broker` is the host name that sign to my local host `message broker`

`Controller:`

```
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publish;

    public GtsDocumentsController(IPublishEndpoint publish)
    {
        _publish = publish;
    }

  [HttpPut("add-seen")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddSeenHistory([FromBody] AddSeenHistoryCommand command)
    {
        await _publish.Publish(command);
        await documentCommandFacade.AddSeenHistory(command);
        return Ok();
    }
```

outbox pattern work fine if my `Message broker` is `Down`

but when its `Up` its like `delivery service` `does not` deliver messages to the `broker`

`i have no idea why it does not work.`

Comment: Use the [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Outbox) to confirm you're using it correctly. If you need further help, contact [support](https://masstransit.io/support).

Answer (score 0):

after 5 hours i fixed the bug with updating the nuget packages